# How to handle Method returning nullptr for shared_ptr in SWIG (C++ to Java)

Tags: java, c++, swig, nullptr

I need to port an existing C++ library to Java. In the C++ code there is a factory method:

```
std::shared_ptr<Role> createRole(std::string name)
```

which will return a `nullptr` if it was not possible to create  the Role.

Unfortunately if I try to port this code with SWIG it will fail silently at this point. I guess that is because Java doesn't know about `nullptr` and SWIG is most likely ignoring it. Is my assumption right? Because I'm originally a Java developer and don't know much about SWIG and C++...

Sadly I can't change the existing C++ code. Is there any workaround for this? Or will I have to write a Wrapper for this special case? This problem occures in 4 or 5 places in the project.

Comment: How is `std::shared_ptr<Role>` translated? I guess using Java's `null` as equivalent to C++'s `nullptr` could be a possible solution.

Comment: I don't know it exactly. SWIG seems to map them to Role (the Java Role class SWIG generated). The shared_ptr is mentioned in the SWIG interface file with %shared_ptr(Role)

Comment: Would I have to modify the SWIG generated file and add the `null` in case the c++ library method returns a `nullptr`? Which files should I modify, I don't want to blow up the SWIG code.

Comment: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/CPlusPlus11.html#CPlusPlus11_null_pointer_constant

Comment: What do you mean _hang_?

Comment: @Alexander Solovets Sry, "hang" was wrong. It fails silently without any exception.

Comment: @Simon Kraemer Yes I saw the documentation. But does that mean the application shouldn't crash at this point?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is highly likely in your code. I just checked out the following code with gcc-4.8 and swig-2.0, and it worked perfectly:

**test.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Test {
  public:
  std::shared_ptr<std::string> test(bool isNull) {
    return isNull ? nullptr : std::make_shared<std::string>("test");
  }
};
```

**test.i**

```
%module "test"

%include "std_shared_ptr.i"
%include "std_string.i"

%shared_ptr( std::string )

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"
```

**check.py**

```
import test
t = test.Test()
print t.test(True)
print t.test(False)
```

The output of `python check.py` is:

> None 
>   <Swig Object of type 'std::shared_ptr< std::string > *' at 0x7f03436501e0>swig/python detected a memory leak of type
>   'std::shared_ptr< std::string > *', no destructor found.

Comment: Guess I will have to check the library and my code again. Many thanks for clarifying this issue from your side.